# DataTable.Select() not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

In my datatable I have two rows with multiple columns.

One of the columns are `ItemID` and their values are `2215,2216`.

When I use the following statement:

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ItemID='2215'");
```

It returns both rows. It's not filtering.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work if your table has data with the structure you described.

```
var dr = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<int>("ItemID") == 2215
    select row;

DataTable dtSelected = dr.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ItemID=2215");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ItemID might be of type int,there is no need of single quotes in int type.

try this

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ItemID=2215");
```

Comment: What is the data type of ItemID?

Comment: the data type is Int32

Comment: Ok Try this,
`DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Convert(ItemID, 'System.String') ='2215'");`

Comment: this is also return all rows. Also DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
                dtCloned.Columns["ItemID"].DataType = typeof(Int32);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
                }
                  dr = dt.Select("Convert(ItemID, 'System.Int32') =2215");
                NewDR = dr[0]; this is also return both rows

Comment: @SidM Sorry, but your answer did not solve my problem, but your comment! Which says dt.Select("Convert(ItemID.... and so on. !So can't up vote your answer, as it would be misleading to the readers and who are trying to solve issue of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Select("PeriodName='" + dr["PeriodName"].ToString() + "'")){
    row["PeriodName"].ToString()
}
```

Comment: @NahuelIanni A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment from @SidM I used this approach

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Convert(ItemID, 'System.Int32') =2215");
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

if itemID is integer then you don't know single quotes.

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ItemID=2215");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue today and I discovered it had something to do with the previous changes to the data table not being accepted yet. Try accepting changes before calling `.Select(...)`. Addionally, as others have mentioned, you don't need the single quote marks if `ItemID` is always an `int` (I don't believe that is the cause of your issues though).

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ItemID=2215");
```

I also tried adding basically every combination of the `DataViewRowState` filters, but no combination worked! Some returned no records, some would only return modified records (even though I included `Unchanged`).

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ItemID=2215",
    DataViewRowState.OriginalRows|DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Note: `OriginalRows | CurrentRows` would be the equivalent of "all row states." I also tried other combinations as well.